# GAE Blobstore file-like API deprecation timeline (py 2.7 runtime)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

This is a question for the App Engine team.

Last week we realized that the App Engine team had marked the file-like API for writing and reading to the blobstore as being deprecated and likely to be removed in the future. We have quite a bit of infrastructure relying on that API that now we need to port to the alternative they suggest (Google Cloud Storage) and this is not a trivial effort (especially considering our current backlog). So the question is: how soon will this file-like API be unavailable? It's fairly important for us to know as depending on the answer, we might shuffle our backlog to prioritize the porting of using the Blobstore to GCS.

Thanks.

Comment: An answer or guidance would be great.

Comment: Aside to your actual question: you can create your own file-like API for the blobstore by having a function that takes file data and uploads (POSTs) it to a blobstore upload handler and wrapping the whole thing so that it acts similar to how you use the file API. It's not the same as the current API but it might suit your needs as a short term fix. The blobstore itself (and it's upload handlers) are not being deprecated currently and are covered by the deprecation policy so you know they will be sticking around for a while even if Google decides to deprecate them.

Comment: @BryceCutt thanks for the suggestion, the core issue is that we have a very tight backlog and whatever solution we decided to implement will have to be re-prioritized, which would be easier if the App Engine team would give at least a rough guidance so that we don't waste developer hours on something that isn't super urgent (which this might well be).

Comment: I completely agree. I asked questions on the mailing list about it when they first announced the deprecation and didn't get much of a useful reply. Since being able to write blobs is very important to us as well I spent a few hours making sure I could create an alternative solution like the one I mentioned in my comment so we have something to fall back on in case the timeline turns out to be short. It's not perfect or complete but at least now I know I have an alternative I can work on if they gave me only a short amount of time to switch.

Comment: @BryceCutt just got official word from Chris Ramsdale. I posted as an answer for all interested to see.

Comment: This is a link to this question on Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/deprecated/google-appengine/b0bElNbdVDU/NGCs9S95Z_kJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official response from Chris Ramsdale, Product Manager, Google App Engine:

> while there's currently no defined date for decommissioning this API, we are committed to supporting it throughout the remainder of the year (2013).  please don't hesitate to reach out to me directly [redacted], if you have further questions (this thread is fine as well).

Comment: @ChrisRamsdale, can you point me to the replacement for the files api? Thanks,