# How to backup image files uploaded and stored as blobs in GAE Blobstore(Python)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore, app-engine-ndb

How to backup (and restore) image files uploaded and stored as blobs in GAE Blobstore(Python)

I have gone through the [GAE help doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin) on this topic. I could not find any way but I am sure there must be a very simple and intuitive way to do this since this is a fundamental need to develop any big commercial web app

Although a feature to download the backed up data would be better but I am even ok with Google Cloud Storage based approach if some definite guide is present for the same

I want to use the backup of my web app data in case of some accidental data deletion or corruption.. I plan to use the Datastore Admin to backup my NDB entities which could be easily restored using the same.. I was hoping for a similar solution(backup and also easy restore) for the image(picture) files stored as blobs in Blobstore..

I have gone through this [GAE Blobstore help page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) and it does not say anything about its deprecation (Files API is deprecated and I am not using that)

Comment: I do not understand your question. You say: blobs in GAE NDB Python and not blobstore. You can use the app backup restore in the datastore admin.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, voscausa.. I have edited my question to be more clear.. pl let me know if it is still unclear..

Comment: @gsinha I answered your question in point number 2. Even if you don't want to move away from blobstore (as I suggested in point number 1), the best way to back blobstore objects up is with a TaskQueue and to a GCS or AWS S3 as described in my answer.

Comment: It is clear now. But why do you need a backup. You have uploded the image files, so you have a backup, or ????

Comment: Thanks voscausa.. I want to use the backup of my web app data in case of some accidental data deletion or corruption.. (added this part, now, to my question too)

Answer (score 1):

1. I would advice against storing images in the AppEngine blobstore to store anything given that it's set for deprecation (and has been so for the last few months). So, in addition to back up I would **strongly** suggest migrating your app to store images directly in Google Cloud Storage asap.
2. The best way to back up images stored in Blobstore is to create a migration via TaskQueues. In this migration, grab each of the blobs and store them to a container which can be AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage (via boto library). The reason you need to make is TaskQueue is because it will likely take a LONG time if you have lots of images stored in the blobstore.

Here's the SO question I asked and got a response about:
[GAE Blobstore file-like API deprecation timeline (py 2.7 runtime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903025/gae-blobstore-file-like-api-deprecation-timeline-py-2-7-runtime)

Comment: Thanks for your reply rdodev.. But i did not find anything about the future deprecation of blobstore on Google page[https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/].. Instead, they show it as the first method to store images.. Files API is deprecated and i am not using that..

Comment: I agree with rdodev Google is moving away from blobstore. But the backup restore of app engine also uses the blobstore.

Comment: @gsinha you're right, I meant the file-like API for blobstore is the one that got deprecated. However, I would still highly recommend moving away from it and use Google Cloud Storage instead. For one, it's an object store that can support large files, secondly, you have access to the objects from outside the app and third it doesn't suffer from api limitations like blobstore (or datastore for that matter) have.

Comment: Thanks rdodev again(+1).. I want to use the backup of my web app data in case of some accidental data deletion or corruption.. I plan to use the Datastore Admin to backup my NDB entities which could be easily restored using the same.. I was hoping for a similar solution(backup and also easy restore) for the image(picture) files stored as blobs in Blobstore.. If I use AWS, I think I would have to manually restore them individually..

Comment: @gsinha unfortunately no. There's isn't an equivalent like the one for datastore, I wish! :)